# Classical physics background for GR

Tags: general-relativity, classical-mechanics, education

I'm a PhD mathematician trying to learn some general relativity from books like Schutz and Carroll. I understand the tensor analysis as presented in these books, but my physics background is limited to classical mechanics and basic electrodynamics, and I would like to see a list of (concise, if possible - I'm 74)  references for the other topics that I need to know something about (like fluids and thermodynamics).

Comment: A mathematician should learn GR from better books, namely Wald and Straumann.